# Merge arrays in object

Tags: json, merge, jq

I have an object that is just a bunch of arbitrary keys with each an array:

```
{
  "foo": [
    "hello",
    "world"
  ],
  "bar": [
    "foobar"
  ]
}
```

How can I return the merged arrays in this object. The expected output would be:

```
[
  "hello",
  "world",
  "foobar"
]
```

Comment: Are you concerned with uniqeness?  Can't you just use [`concat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a list of the values and concatenate the elements in that list:

```
[.[]] | add
```

Create a list of each element in each array:

```
[.[][]]
```

I'd prefer the first one since it parses easier in my mind.

Answer (score 1):

Generalizing a bit:

```
jq '[..|scalars]' input.json
```